# Is it possible to check if GPU is available without using deep learning packages like TF or torch?

Tags: python, gpu

I would like to check if there is access to GPUs by using any packages other than tensorflow or PyTorch. I have found the `psutil.virtual_memory().percent` function that returns the usage of the GPU. However, this function could still return 0 if GPUs are utilized but not loaded. I wonder if there is another way to check it. Thanks!

Comment: Define what you mean by `access to GPUs`. accessible by what/for what exactly?

Comment: Thanks for asking for clarification. I want to check if a user has GPU in their machines so I will be sure that tensorflow will use GPU for ML training when the user runs it. Please let me know if more details is needed.

Comment: You could compile a small CUDA Test program and try to execute it I guess, but it would probably be safer to just import tensorflow (it must be present in the machine) and check if it detected a compatible GPU. After all: even if there is a CUDA capable card that theoretically supports tensorflow, you still don't know if tensorflow was installed correctly with GPU support

Comment: I didn't want to give over info unrelated to the question but this method does not work for me. I am using multiprocessing module inside of my script and if I import DL packages before creating subprocesses my script doesn't work. So I have to check if GPU is utilized before spawning subprocesses and importing tensorflow. Hope I explained well.

Comment: You don't need to import it in your script.... You could create a seperate python file that just checks if tensorflow is present and can utilize the GPU and then outputs 0 or 1. From your main script, you just execute said script, parse the result and act accordingly

Comment: Indeed it is a nice approach, but I have another constraints that it cant work.

Comment: How about you put your constraints into your question? It is impossible to answer if you don't specify them

Comment: I think my question is quite constrained. I want to learn which packages (exc. dl packages) or functions I can use to check whether GPUs are available.  The focus is not on what practice or general approaches to check it. I am specifically asking for the packages, that's all. Many thanks for your effort but the suggestions that you were given me are not related to my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is also another library called GPUtil that gives you the available GPUs as a list.

You simply need to install it as a pip command `pip install GPUtil` and then run the following

```
import GPUtil
print(GPUtil.getAvailable()) # Returns a list of available GPUs. Will be empty of no GPU is available
print(GPUtil.showUtilization()) #Returns a list of GPUs and their processing and memory utilization
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. One small question: does this package somehow uses CUDA?

Comment: No, I checked its github repo, and does not use it. https://github.com/anderskm/gputil Thanks!